# Does ADMM promise to converge if there are binary variables in each agent's constraints?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, binary, non-convex-optimization

As is stated in chapter 9 of Boyd *et al*.<sup>[1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1561/2200000016)</sup>, ADMM can be used as a heuristic method for solving non-convex problems.

Here, my case contains binary variables and it is more special since **the binary variable only appears in individual problem** and has no connection with other agents. The multi-agent problem in my case can be formulated as follows:

$$\text{min}\quad\sum\limits_if_i(\boldsymbol{x_i}) \\
\text{s.t.}\quad \sum\limits_i\boldsymbol{x_i}=0,\\
g_i(\boldsymbol{x_i},y_i)\leq0, \\
y_i\in\{0,1\},\\
\boldsymbol{x_i}\in\Omega_i
$$
$\boldsymbol{x_i}$ is continuous, $\Omega_i$ is a convex set and $f_i$ is a convex function. $g_i$ is a linear function. You can find an example below in the comment section.

I want to solve the above problem in a distributed manner by exploiting the exchange problem formulation in Boyd's paper (Chapter 7). Hence, the binary variable $y_i$ only appears in each individual constraint and individual problems are MIPs, which can be solved easily with commercial solvers.

I am wondering **whether ADMM in this case can converge to the global optimum**. Or is there any modification of standard ADMM to achieve the global optimum?
If not, does the standard ADMM of this case **promise to converge to a suboptimal point**?

Thank you for your kind help.

---

1. Stephen Boyd, Neal Parikh, Eric Chu, Borja Peleato, Jonathan Eckstein, [Distributed Optimization and Statistical Learning via the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers](http://dx.doi.org/10.1561/2200000016), Foundations and Trends in Machine Learning, Volume 3, Number 1, 2011.

Comment: What does "suboptimal" point mean? If the problem is nonconvex, then the KKT stationary point could be a local (or global if lucky I think) optima. Right?

Also, can you disclose your $g_i(\mathbf{x}_i, y_i)$ function? You say $g_i$ is a linear function (or is it bilinear?).

Comment: @user550103 Thanks for your kind reply. By 'suboptimal', I want to know if ADMM can converge to a feasible point under this circumstance (better if close to optimal point). In my case, I want to realize a distributed mechanism without disclosing each agent's function and parameters. $g_i$ is a linear function (Big-M method actually), which can be expressed as: $- M*y_i\leq \mathbf{x_i}_j\leq M*(1-y_i)$.

Comment: It means your parameter of interest is only $\mathbf{x}_i$, correct? This $y_i \in \{0,1 \}$ can actually be seen as a "label". That is, only $\mathbf{x}_i$ is a parameter of interest while minimizing the sum of finite functions, right? In other words, $\min_{ \mathbf{x}_i } \ \sum_i f_i(  \mathbf{x}_i  )$. If yes, then "to my eyes", this problem looks like a continuous optimization problem. Thus, the classical ADMM convergence proof holds for this use case.

Comment: @user550103 Yes. The objective has no direct relation with $y_i$. In my case, $y_i$ can be viewed as a label to distinguish whether an agent is a seller or a buyer. But it does have impact on the objective. Please allow me to present a simple example with two agents. Let $\mathbf{x_i}=[x_{i1},x_{i2},x_{i3}]$, and $f_i(\mathbf{x_i})=x_{i3}^2+5*x_{i2}$, the constraints are $x_{11}+x_{21}=0;\quad 0\leq x_{i2}\leq M*y_i\quad \forall i=1,2;\quad -M*y_i\leq x_{i1}\leq M*(1-y_i)\quad \forall i=1,2;\quad x_{i1}+x_{i2}\geq 4*x_{i3},\forall i=1,2$.    Does this in line with what you say?

Comment: If I were you, I will try with a small example to check whether the model "runs" in CVX-like solver. If it works in CVX-like solver, then it simply means your problem formulation is convex. Consequently, the sequences generated by ADMM (for convex) should converge to a KKT point (or global optimal solution) under suitable constraint qualifications, asymptotically.

Comment: @user550103 Thank you very much. I have implemented my MIP problem with Mosek on MATLAB. With my data, ADMM can indeed converge to the optimal point. I am just wondering whether it is always the case?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Sorry for that. It's "Boyd, S., Parikh, N., Chu, E., Peleato, B., & Eckstein, J. (2011). Distributed optimization and statistical learning via the alternating direction method of multipliers. Foundations and Trends® in Machine learning, 3(1), 1-122."